# RxSwift subclassing best practices

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a view model that's being used in two flows and has gotten to the stage where it should really be split out into a super class and two subclasses. However, I'm getting confused as the best way to go about performing some subclassing.

On creation of the view model, I pass in all the interactions that could happen from the view like so:

### View

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var nextButton: UIButton!

    private var presenter: SomeViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter.configure(nextButtonTapped: nextButton.rx.tap.asDriver())
    }

}
```

Then I can handle these actions within my view model like so:

### ViewModel

```
class SomeViewModel {

    private let normalFlow: Bool
    private let diposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(normalFlow: Bool) {
        self.normalFlow = normalFlow
    }

    func configure(nextButtonTapped: Driver<Void>) {
        handle(nextButtonTapped: nextButtonTapped)
        // call to any other input handlers here...    
    }

    func handle(nextButtonTapped: Driver<Void>) {
        nextButtonTapped.drive(onNext: { [unowned self] in
            guard self.safetyCheckOnePasses(), safetyCheckTwoPasses() else {
                return
            }
            if normalFlow {
                // do some set of actions
            } else {
                // do another set of actions
            }
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    func safetyCheckOnePasses() -> Bool {
        // perform some sanity check...
        return true
    }

    func safetyCheckTwoPasses() -> Bool {
        // perform another sanity check...
        return true
    }

}
```

I'm getting confused as to what the best way to override the `handle(nextButtonTapped: Driver<Void>)` is because I still want those sanity checks to happen at the start of the `onNext` for every subclass, but I want the body after that to be different for the different subclasses. What would be the best way to go about this without duplicating code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rx is part of the functional paradigm and as such, subclassing is not appropriate.

Move your `safetyCheckOnePasses()` and `safetyCheckTwoPasses()` functions out of the class (or at least make them static.) That way they can be reused without needing an instance.